# Autoplay Adobe AIR application

Tags: air

Is there a way to tell Microsoft Windows to AutoPlay an Adobe AIR application?

I have an AIR application on the users sd card, and I would like it to run whenever the user inserts the card into his computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to package it as an executable.